# Regular Expression to find words separated with space, backtracking

Tags: java, regex, backtracking

I have to find words separated by space. What best practice to do it with the smallest backtracking?

I found this solution:

```
Regex: \d+\s([a-zA-Z]+\\s{0,1}){1,} in a sentence
Input: 1234 this is words in a sentence
```

So, `this is words` - i have to check using regex `([a-zA-Z]+\\s{0,1}){1,}` and words `in a sentence` i have to check by constant words in regex `in a sentences`.

But in this case regex101.com gives me debug with 4156 steps and this is Catastrophic Backtracking. Any way to avoid it?

I have other more complicated example, where it takes 86000 steps and it does not validate.

Main problem, that i have to find all words separated by space, but in the same time regex contains words separated by space (constants). This is where i have Catastrophic Backtracking.

I have to do this using Java.

Comment: You can replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `\w` to represent all non-whitespace characters, can't you?

Comment: I don't know if I'm misunderstanding your problem but can't you simply use `String.split()`?

Comment: Would it help if you split the string based on spaces/dots/whitespace and go from there?

Comment: Try using a possessive quantifier with `[a-zA-Z]++`.

Comment: This expression `"\\d+\s[a-zA-Z\\s]+ in a sentence"` [matches in 34 steps](https://regex101.com/r/qQ7kI5/2). Unfortunately, it allows multiple spaces in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find words separated by `space`.So you should say at least `1 or more space`.You can use this instead which takes just 37 steps.

```
\d+\s([a-zA-Z]+\s+)+in a sentence
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/4

For java double escape all ie `\d==\\d`

Comment: it is a good solution. i have a generator of regex and input string for them and now, using your optimization i get more performance. i will test now, may be i will have any other question about it. thank you! i'll mark later.

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the String into a String array, then find the size of the array after eliminating any members of the array that do not match your definition of a word (ex. a whitespace or puncuation)

```
String[] mySplitString = myOriginalString.split(" ");
for(int x = 0; x < mySplitString.length; x++){
    if(mySplitString[x].matches("\\w.*"/*Your regex for a word here*/)) words++;
}
```

mySplitString is an array of Strings that have been split from an original string. All whitespace characters are removed and substrings that were before, after, or in-between whitespaces are placed into the new String array. The for-loop runs through the split String array and checks to make sure that each array member contains a word (characters or numbers atleast once) and adds it to a total word count.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you want to match any word separeted by space plus the sentence "in a sentence".

You can try the following solution:

```
(in a sentence)|(\S+)
```

As seen in this example on regex101: [Exemple](https://regex101.com/r/aY8vD9/1)

The regex matchs in 61 steps.
You might have problems with punctuation after the "in a sentence" sentence. Make some tests.

I hope I was helpfull.

Comment: solution by @vks it takes 37 steps